# How to pass value from g:select tag

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.0

I want to pass value from the selection bar to the textarea but failed, saying description of null object is not defined. 
${dbList} is a list of DB object. DB object contains a property called description.How do I make the textarea display that description property.

```
<g:select name="copyDB" from="${dbList}" value="copyDB" 
onchange="document.getElementById("text").value=${copyDB.description}" />

<textarea  id="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

add attr optionKey & optionValue to tag g:select

```html
<g:select name="copyDB" from="${dbList}" value=""
optionKey="[a property of DB object]" optionValue="description" 
onchange="document.getElementById("text").value=${copyDB.description}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I have multiple properties as optionKey? since I have put DBname property as a optionkey.

Comment: The easiest way to look at any html speciality in grails is what does g:select produce ? the final output is a `select . option ..option /select` html tag - so in short how many <option name='1'>record 1</option> names can you define in the option tag of a html field ?  Answer is 1.  https://www.html.am/html-codes/forms/html-select-lists.cfm. So in short 1 `optionKey` which is the inner name of the option and `optionValue` equating to it's value on the outside of the produced html -

Comment: using jquery you could iterate through the select options and add in `data-db='someDb'` for each option but I warn you this is going to get complex since you be doing it to start which you may as well use javascript to draw out the g:select manually and assign `data-db` tags in at the same time, when attempting to post the form you need to manually find / parse selected option and get it's data option back - you be better off having another hiddenField which you update when select is triggered by end user to select the required db for that selection

Comment: Sorry 1 last comment part of above which is the javascript to iterate through when generating the select could be better done using a taglib https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselection/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/ajaxdependancyselection/AutoCompleteTagLib.groovy#L49 -  the other part which after user selects a selection and javascript picks up data element and fills another hidden form field still would need to be added. I should point out you have raised 1 question then gone off to ask something else in comment - think about all this raise new question if required